# How to import data from excel sheet/csv using javascript without using activeX

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to import excel data to populate charts using javascript but the problem is i am using activeX objects which is only supported by Internet explorer..**i want some other way to import data and store in array to populate graphs in my web page**